# How can I adapt the width of an Image retrieved by URL to a View container in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I would like to retrieve an image from an url, and insert it inside a `View` adapting the size to the container.

This is an `expo` where I tried to do it.
https://snack.expo.io/Hk1rsfaHU

How you can see there are 3 columns having the same width(flex 1), in the first there is the image.

I wish this `Image` was contained inside the `View`, adapting the width to the container and maintaining the correct aspect ratio.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `src` to `source` in your `<Image />`:

```
  <Image source={{uri: 'https://i2.wp.com/www.xpeppers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/react-native-preview.png?resize=580%2C357'}} 
    resizeMode='contain' style={styles.image}
  />
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

**Working Demo:**

https://snack.expo.io/SJdlzQTr8